# woocommerce and pretty permalinks and error 404

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm fighting with WooCommerce for weeks. I'll explain.

I'm doing a website with wordpress having WooCommerce integrated online shop. This website will also have multilingual so I have built WPML (but would not have to affect it said if anything).

By SEO issues have put the permalinks as `input name` which is the most optimal.

To WooCommerce have defined the permalinks as `/store/%product_cat%`

I have no cache plugin in wordpress and I've disabled the php server cache.

The issue is that I have categories and products, I can play with no problem, but when they stop working a few hours and to give the store page gives a 404 error http://dev.escalamas.com/tienda .

Yesterday for example, tap the permalinks in the morning, throughout the day was, do not touch anything on the page and I was going regularly and this morning has stopped working.

Thought you had it controlled no caching of any kind and modification of permalinks of WooCommerce but is seen not.

Someone has the wisdom enough to hecharme a hand?

If I reinstall WooCommerce or change the permalinks and back as they were leaving work .. seems frisked, but I have the cache enabled .....